# JSON schema validation for first array element

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am interested in validating some JSON logic to check for a certain value is in place for for the first element in an array. I would like to achieve this via JSON schema if possible. For Example, I would like to check to see if the first element is "manager":

```
  "employees": [
    {
      "manager": "Band35",
      "name": "Tom"
    },
    {
      "developer": "Band25",
      "name": "Kelly"
    },
    {
      "analyst": "Band25",
      "name": "Jack"
    }    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`items` keyword](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.4.1) to validate an array.

> If "items" is an array of schemas, validation succeeds if each element
>   of the instance validates against the schema at the same position, if
>   any.

This means you should have `items: [firstSchema]` if you want to check that the first item in your array should pass `firstSchema`.

For example, if you want the first item in the array to be a specific string...

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "const": "myFirstItemString"
    }
  ]
}
```

For checking a specific property name of an object, you need to use [`propertyNames` keyword](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.8).

You can test this easily by using https://jsonschema.dev

Comment: Note in the latest draft, `items` now needs to be `prefixitems` for tuple validation like this

Answer (score -1):

Deserialize JSON into an object (depending on language) and check for the value of the "manager" property on the first element of the array, would be helpful if you were more specific on what language or tools you're using (Example in JS below)

```
var validated = (JSON.parse(json).employees[0].manager === "Band35");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP said they wanted to use JSON Schema, which is language agnostic.

Comment: You're correct, thanks for the clarification on my part :)